# Type deduction for std::array literals

Tags: stdarray

Wont compile. The type of the elements cant be infrefered.

```cpp
auto rng = std::array{{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6},...};
```

CTAD for each argument results in lots of retyping:

```cpp
auto rng = std::array{std::array{1,2}, std::array{3,4}, std::array{5,6},...};
```

If you specify the type of the elements, then the size of the array `N` can no longer be deduced:

```cpp
auto rng = std::array<std::array<std::array<int, 2>>, N>{{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6},...};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++20 provides a `std::to_array` function where you can provide the element type and while still deducing the length

```cpp
auto rng = std::to_array<std::array<int, 2>>({{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6},...});
```